# Can Kafka's stream API help distribute hundreds of pagination requests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, hapi-fhir

I am building an application that reaches out to a FHIR API that implements paging, and only gives me a maximum of 100 results per page. However, our app requires the aggregation of these pages in order to hand over metadata to the UI about the *entire* result set.

When I loop through the pages of a large result set, I get **HTTP status 429 - Too many requests**. I am wondering if handing off these requests to a kafka service will help me get around this issue and maybe increase performance. I've read through the Intro and Use Cases sections of the Kafka documentation, but am still unclear as to whether implementing this tool will help.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting [429 errors](https://httpstatuses.com/429) because you're making too many requests too quickly; you need to implement rate limiting.

As far as whether to use Kafka, a big part of that is whether your result set can fit in memory. If you can fit it in memory, then I would really suggest avoiding bringing in a separate service ([KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)). If not, then yes, you can use Kafka. But I'd suggest taking a long think about whether you can use a relational datastore, because they're much more flexible. Or maybe even reading/writing directly to the disk

Answer (score 0):

I were you, before I look into Kafka, I would try to solve why you are getting a 429 error. I would not leave that unnoticed. I would try to see how I am going to solve that.

I would looking into the following:

1) **Sleep your process**. The server response usually includes a Retry-after header in the response with the number of seconds you are supposed to wait before retrying.

2) **[Exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff)** If the server's response does not tell you how long to wait, you can retry your request by inserting pauses by yourself in between.

Do keep it mind, before implementing sleep, it warrants extensive testing. You would have to make sure that your existing functionality does not get impacted.

To answer your question if Kafka would help you or not, the answer is  **it may or may not**, with the limited info I can get from your question. Do understand that implementing Kafka would change your network architecture. You are bringing in a streaming platform to the equation. You would most probably implement caching which would aggregate your results. But at the moment all these concepts are at a very holistic level. I would suggest that you first ought to solve the 429 error and then warrant if a proper technical reason is present to implement Kafka which would improve your website's performance.

Comment: Adding sleep or backoff could potentially cause the client to drop messages, though.